# How to use Phaser 3.17 GameConfig object in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, phaser-framework, typescript-definitions

After updating Phaser to 3.17 with

```
npm install phaser@3.17.0
```

I now get these Typescript errors:

```
const config: GameConfig = {
    scene: [BootScene, StartScene, GameScene, GameOver],
    input: {
        keyboard: true
    }
}
```

> Cannot find name 'GameConfig'

When looking in the `.d.ts` file, I guess I now have to use:

```
const config: Phaser.Types.Core.GameConfig = {
    scene: [BootScene, StartScene, GameScene, GameOver],
    input: {
        keyboard: true
    }
}
```

But now, `scene` is no longer recognised as part of GameConfig!

> The expected type comes from property 'scene' which is declared here on type 'GameConfig'

I have no idea what this means... is this a bug in the `.d.ts` file?

Comment: I'm using `type GameConfig = Phaser.Types.Core.GameConfig;` until this is fixed.